# Show that the equation has no solutions

Tags: number-theory

Show that the equation $$7y^3+2=z^3$$ has no solutions $y, z \in ℤ$.

I've seen for equations of the form $ax+by=c$ a method that was used was that there is a solution if $gcd(a,b) | c$. This doesn't work for this type of equation because if we rearranged to $$7y^3-z^3=-2$$ and then found $gcd(7, -1)= 1$ we have that $1|2$ so there should be a solution.
How should this be approached?

Comment: Note that you rearranged the equation incorrectly - it should read $7y^3 - z^3 = -2$

Comment: I fixed it, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $3=(7-1)/2$ and recall that $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}$ whenever $p$ is an odd prime which does not divide $x$. It follows that
$$
2\equiv 7y^3+2 = z^3 \equiv \pm 1\pmod{7},
$$
which is a contradiction.